# Get outerHTML text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, google-tag-manager, outerhtml

I am working on Google Tag Manager and I am having trouble getting the outerHTML text.

```
<div class="a"><i class="b"></i> email </div>
```

I tried multiple ways but I can't get it to work.

```
document.querySelector("div.a").outerHTML;
document.querySelector("div.a").outerHTML.textContent;
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div.a").outerHTML);
console.log(document.querySelector("div.a").outerHTML.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="a"><i class="b"></i> email </div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("div.a").textContent`

Comment: `outerHTML` and `text` are contradictory. Please revise to be more clear about what you're after.

Comment: Agreed, the question needs more clarity. What is the desired result that you are trying to get?

Comment: Sorry. I need to get the string "email" from div.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on `Node.textContent` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

In the snippet below, notice that `.textContent` includes the leading/trailing spaces, whereas `.innerText` does not

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div.a");

console.log({
  outerHTML: div.outerHTML,
  innerHTML: div.innerHTML,
  innerText: div.innerText,
  textContent: div.textContent
});
```

```html
<div class="a"><i class="b"></i> email </div>
```